# Windows Detailed Process Information

Tags: windows, windows-7, process, process-explorer

If I execute the following command via the command line:-

**wmplayer.exe /play "c:\VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.VOB"**

Is there any way to get info for the running process from the system that also includes the full command line executed (similar to ps -aux on Linux)?

"**tasklist /v**" only tells me that "wmplayer" is running, not which file is playing (e.g. **c:\VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.VOB**)

The sysinternals.com command pslist doesn't appear to give me that info either.  Is it possible to do this on Windows?

I'd appreciate any help you can offer me.

*Kind Regards,*

SteJav

Comment: Found the solution (or at least a colleague did!):-

WMIC PROCESS

does the trick.

SteJav

Comment: post it as the answer to your question then, so you can mark it as accepted

Comment: just a warning that processes can manipulate that value: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sysinternals.com **procexp** (Process Explorer) can also do this. Think of it as task manager on steroids. Double-click on the process name, and the *Image* tab will show you the command line. Process Explorer will also let you see all files & handles the process has open, and will let you force close individual handles among other useful functions.